# How is $\gamma^{\mu}$ defined in the anti commutation relation $\{{\gamma_{5},\gamma^{\mu}}\}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conventions, definition, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

how is $\gamma^{\mu}$ defined in the anti commutation relation $\{\gamma_{5},\gamma^{\mu}\}$? does it make a difference if you write the index ${^\mu}$ lower? what does usually change if the index is lowered or on the contrary written above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/84967).

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma^{\mu}$ are defined from their anticommutation relation:

$$\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu} I_4 $$

Where I use the $(+---)$ convention for $\eta$ and $I_4$ is the 4x4 identity matrix.

There are many possible choices to express such matrices, one of them is: (Dirac basis)

$$\gamma^0= \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$ \gamma^1 = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$ \gamma^2= \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
-i & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$ \gamma^3 = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

then
$$\gamma_{\mu}= \eta_{\mu\nu}\gamma^{\nu}$$
where $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is the metric tensor, which means:

$\gamma_0=\gamma^0$; $\gamma_i=-\gamma^i$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: The *dirac basis* is defined by what you've written. The gamma matrices are defined with their abstract properties and there are many choices of $\gamma^0$, of $\gamma^1$, etc. Not worth a downvote but I think this is important.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution: you are completely right, I've edited my answer.